# Pycharm run the code adding the current working dir to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

Trying to figure this out, because there is an inconsistency between when I run the code from Pycharm and from terminal.

Pycharm add automatically the current working directory; so if I add a module that is contained in my CWD, that is not in Pythonpath, it works just fine.

But when running from terminal, Python does complain, because my import statements refer to modules that are not reachable, because the CWD is not added to PYTHONPATH (I did verify this printing out the content of the variable, while running from Pycharm and from Terminal).

So at this point I am assuming that in my startup code, I need to add to Pythonpath the current directory, or this is not correct? I have no way to tell where the final user may put my code in; I just assume that the whole directory containing all my different modules, is located in a specific place.

To be more specific, this is where I am at:

- my CWD when I run from Pycharm is `/apps/myapp/logic/`, I run the script after `cd` in that directory, and I call the script with `./myscript.py`
- The script has the `#!/usr/bin/python3` line as first line, instead of running it with `python3 -m myscript.py`
- The error I get, is when loading a module that is either in the same directory of my script (`/apps/myapp/logic/`) or one level above (`/apps/myapp/`); sadly the module load happen before my `__main__` is running; so I can't add to `sys.path` the current directory from which the script run.
- All these issues are not happening if I just run the script from Pycharm

Comment: Are you sure the issue is the current working directory not being added, as opposed to the current working directory being different (e.g., being the same as the directory your script is in for one case but not the other, or being `.` for one but an absolute path for the other)?

Comment: Anyway, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) explain. `sys.path[0]` should always be the path to your script's directory if available, `''` (which is treated the same as `'.'`) if not. However, `''` or `'.'` or something else could be added by a custom `PYTHONPATH`, `site`, or…

Comment: Finally, the usual ways to solve this problem are (a) use `setuptools` to install your modules into site-packages, (b) use `setuptools` to install your modules (usually into site-packages) and auto-create an "entry-point" script that finds them wherever they were installed, (c) find the modules based on relative path from the script's own path, or (d) have some configuration to point to the path (usually only used for plugin directories and the like). Finding them off the current working directory is a weird thing to do. Why do you want that in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did triple check and I get a "module not found" because when I run the code from terminal, it does not have the CWD in PYTHONPATH; while in Pycharm, it does run fine and the CWD is in the PYTHONPATH variable. I do run the code mostly from Pycharm, but now I need to deploy it and I did experience the issue

Comment: I am using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the path of the script that I am running, and as such, I can go to the root of my project easily. Would that be enough to be added to PYTHONPATH, or there is something else that I should do? I did notice no difference (the script fail anyway when running from terminal), if I add the CWD to sys.path with sys,path.insert()

Comment: Do you actually want to get your modules from wherever the CWD happens to be, instead of from the directory the script is in? If so, why do you want that, and why are you asking about `os.path.dirname(__file__)`? If not, why do you keep talking about the CWD in the first place? Either way: if the CWD and the path to the script are different, does PyCharm give you one, the other, or both, and does the command line give you one, the other, or neither?

Comment: I am asking because I can't get my code to work outside pycharm. When the file that has my main is launched, it does the import before run the main function, and one of these imports is in the same directory where the script with the main is. This end up in an error, because I didn't set the CWD in PYTHONPATH yet, due the fact that the main code run after the imports. Should I not import anything until I run main?

Comment: Can you please answer the questions in my last comment? I really can't help you without knowing the answers to those questions.

Comment: Sorry: 1: I may have these modules either in the same folder from which the script is executed, or from one level up, so the desired behavior would be to run `myscript.py` from `/apps/myapp/logic/` and these modules I call, may live either in `apps/myapp/` or `/apps/myapp/logic/`
2: my assumption is that my script runs fine in pycharm, because the CWD is passed by the IDE, so it is visible to the Python3 interpreter; which is why I am mentioning CWD (there is nothing else different otherwise, between running from IDE or terminal)

Comment: OK, so your CWD is `/apps/myapp`, and you're running the script with `python /apps/myapp/logic/myscript.py`? If so, the difference is probably not that PyCharm is somehow getting the CWD into `sys,path` but the command-line Python is not; it's that you don't have the same CWD in both cases. But that's just a guess, because you still haven't actually answered my question about whether the CWD is the same as the path to the script or not, in each case, and I don't know how else to ask that I haven't already tried repeatedly.

Comment: Yes, if get CWD it is the same as expected, pointing at the location where the script is. I run the script without call python directly, since I did add the `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` on the top of the script, but it is worth trying to see if that is affecting how the terminal retrieve the current location of the script. Thanks for the replies !

Answer (score 0):

After various trial and error, and thanks to the info that I did get from the comments; I did find 2 ways to solve the issue.

1) Create a shell script or another python script, which is adding the current directory (where all the files lives), and have no import in this file. Then the script call the script that has the main function.

2) On the top of the module, right after import `sys`, add the statement to add the path, in this way the current directory will be added to the PATH and it will be accessible, when the import try to access the module.

Neither look very nice, but this is all that I was able to find, to solve the issue. Pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do so